# IPA pronunciation of 'Bazinga'

Tags: pronunciation, ipa

You might be familiar with the tv-series the Big Bang Theory. Sheldon, one of the main characters, often says "bazinga". How would I write this in IPA? This is what I have, does that make sense?

/bəˈzɪŋɡɑː/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skQGve3XksU

Comment: Just out of interest. Is the term coined by the show? It's interesting how we instantly understand and accept a complete new made up word so perfectly

Comment: as far as I know, yes. Obviously, context is key here. (This video isn't the first occurrence of the word.) Also, it's fairly similar to 'zing', which has been around longer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be /bəˈzɪŋɡə/. There is no /ɑː/ at the end of the word.